# C# windows forms ComboBox trouble

Tags: c#, winforms

Why I have null in Combobox.SelectedValue? SelectedItem not null, it's anonimous object. DisplayMember works fine.

```
        var item1 =
            new
            {
                Name = "some phrase1",
                Value = 0
            };

        var item2 =
            new
            {
                Name = "some phrase2",
                Value = 1
            };

       _cmb = new ComboBox();
       _cmb.Items.Add(item1);
       _cmb.Items.Add(item2);  

       _cmb.DisplayMember = "Name";
       _cmb.ValueMember = "Value";

       //.....

       //onchange method
       {
            var nulled = _cmb.SelectedValue //why it's null???
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

Obviously because the combo box has no selected item.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx

> The object that is the currently selected item or null if there is no
>   currently selected item.

EDIT; I have tested it, and it returns an object if you select it...  you can't access its properties because the anonymous object but you can use reflection or declare a class, an interface or a struct and use it.

if you get null then the combobox has no selected item.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, ComboBox doesn't work like that with anonymous types.

There *is* the entire object in the `SelectedItem` property, however you have no way of accessing its properties directly, since they are in an anonymous type.

You can either use reflection (but you shouldn't) or create a non-anonymous type with Key/Name and Value properties and use that one instead.

Or use the built-in `KeyValuePair<T, T>` if you only have Key/Name and Value:

```
var item1 = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("some phrase1", 0);
var item2 = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("some phrase2", 1);
```